# Passing parameters to Ant Build file from Java Objects?

Tags: ant

I have a scenario, I am executing a set of JUnit test cases using Ant scripts. The final thing in the ant file is that the report and a mail should be sent to a specified list of users. But to do that i need some information from the test cases executed. I had created a singleton class to keep hold of some information as the test cases were executed. Finally when i am calling the class to send the mail from the Ant script, i want to pass certain values from the singleton class to the mail sending class. I hope i explained it properly! :) 
If you need more info, i am here!

Comment: Don't do the work others have already done for you. Take a look at [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org). Jenkins will automatically do a build on each commit/checkin your developers do, then run all the JUnit tests and email the developers the results. It also keeps the results in a nice, easy to use webpage with graphs and can track trends. Jenkins is simple to setup (it's just a war file that's executed by a Jave process) and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Junit can generate XML formatted reports, which you could parse at the end of your build.

```
<junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="yes">
    <classpath>
        <path refid="test.path"/>
        <pathelement location="${classes.dir}"/>
        <pathelement location="${test.classes.dir}"/>
    </classpath>
    <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${test.reports.dir}">
        <formatter type="xml"/>
        <fileset dir="${test.src.dir}">
            <include name="**/*Test.java"/>
        </fileset>
    </batchtest>
</junit>
```

If your reporting needs are more complex (you mentioned a singleton class) you could consider writing a custom formatter. Described in the [junit task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html) documentation.

```
..
<formatter classname="com.myorg.junit.CustomFormatter"/>
..
```